# Prevent mesh transformation to change frame of image

Tags: ios, swift, image-processing

I want to make app that change face of human as i drag on image. For this purpose i've used 'BCMeshTransformView'. It gives result near about my requirements. When i drag finger on image some pixels are stretched. but real problem behind this scenario is  "with pixels image frame is also distorted". Can anyone suggest way that **will only change pixel within image frame without changes frame of image?**

[Actual result i want...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiDvC.png)

[unfortunately result i get...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e01Zb.png)

```
 //MARK:- touch method
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first
        start_point = touch!.location(in: self.imageView)
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first
        let position = touch!.location(in: self.transformView)
        self.meshBuldgeAtPoint(point: position)

    }


//MARK:- Mesh sludge
 func meshBuldgeAtPoint(point:CGPoint) {

        old_start_point = start_point
        old_end_point = point

     self.transformView.meshTransform = warpTransform(from: start_point,to: point, in:CGSize(width: self.transformView.bounds.size.width, height: self.transformView.bounds.size.height))

    }



// MARK:-  Wrap Image
    func warpTransform(from startPoint:CGPoint,
                       to endPoint:CGPoint, in size:CGSize) -> BCMutableMeshTransform {

        let _startPoint = CGPoint(x: startPoint.x/size.width, y: startPoint.y/size.height)
        let _endPoint = CGPoint(x: endPoint.x/size.width, y: endPoint.y/size.height)
        let dis = distance(a: _startPoint, b: _endPoint)

        let dragDistance = dis

        for i in 0..<mesh.vertexCount {

            var vertex = mesh.vertex(at: i)
            let dis = distance(a: _startPoint, b: vertex.from)
            let myDistance = dis

            let hEdgeDistance = min(vertex.from.x, 1 - vertex.from.x)
            let vEdgeDistance = min(vertex.from.y, 1 - vertex.from.y)
            let hProtection = min(30, pow(hEdgeDistance * 30, 0))/30
            let vProtection = min(30, pow(vEdgeDistance * 30,0))/30

            if (myDistance < dragDistance) {

                let maxDistort = CGPoint(x:(_endPoint.x - _startPoint.x) / 10,
                                         y:(_endPoint.y - _startPoint.y) / 10)

                let normalizedDistance = myDistance/dragDistance
                let normalizedImpact = (cos(normalizedDistance * .pi) + 1)

                vertex.to.x += maxDistort.x * normalizedImpact * hProtection
                vertex.to.y += maxDistort.y * normalizedImpact * vProtection

                mesh.replaceVertex(at: i, with: vertex)
            }
        }

        return mesh
    }
```

Comment: I had spent too much time on it. So, let me know if you're not clear about my question. But Instead of putting on hold if you'll help to solve it then it will be very thankful for me.  @HansHirse

Comment: Can you share how you achieve this?